# C# Watin Find.ByText with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, watin

I have the following problem here:
I'm trying to get a element from a webpage using Watin's Find.ByText. However, I fail to use regex in C#.

This statement will return the desired element.

```
return this.Document.Element(Find.ByText("781|262"));
```

When I try to use regex, I get back the whole page.

```
return this.Document.Element(Find.ByText(new Regex(@"781\|262")));
```

I am trying to get this element:

```
<td>781|262</td>
```

I also tried

```
return this.Document.Element(Find.ByText(Predicate));

private bool Predicate(string s)
{
  return s.Equals("781|262");
}
```

The above works, while this does not:

```
 private bool Predicate(string s)
 {
   return new Regex(@"781\|262").IsMatch(s);
 }
```

I now realized, in the predicate s is the whole page content. I guess the issue is with Document.Element.
Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In c#, the @ sign means that your string is a verbatim string literal. IE, you don't need to scape special characters inside the string, like a file name "C:\\folder\\mifile.txt" vs @"C:\folder\mifile.txt"

Comment: Thank you. I just tried \\| instead of @, still no luck.

Comment: Maybe.. If you use a verbatim string literal and forget that you don't need to scape the special characters, those scape characters will be treated as part of the regex, what is not obviously what you want. ..

Comment: Could you try replacing the vertical bar with \u007c and not using the @ symbol? And if that does not work, with the @ symbol? Also, if you're replying to a comment using a comment, please preface your comment with @username, so they get notified of the reply.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I tried both "781\\u007c262" and "781\u007c262", no luck, will try with a @ now. I also tried @"781\u007c262".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did not realize the Regex will also match the body/html element too, since the pattern is obviously also included in them. I had to specify that the text must begin and end with the pattern by using ^ and $, so it only matches the desired element:

```
^781\u007c262$
```

\u007c matches |, I used this since MSDN documentation also did.

The final code:

```
<td>781|262</td>

return Document.TableCell(Find.ByText(new Regex(@"^\d{3}\|\d{3}$")));
```

Document.TableCell to speedup the search by only trying Regex on td elements.

@ is used to prevent C# from interpreting the \ as escape sequence.

^ is used to only match elements with text beginning with the following pattern
\d{3} match didit 0-9 3 times

\| match | literally

\d{3} match digit 0-9 3 times

$ the element must also end with this pattern

Comment: So it worked then? If yes you can mark this as answer. It will be helpful to people like us.

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you for informing me. I already tried, but you have to wait 3 hours before accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
return this.Document.Element(Find.ByText(new Regex("781\\|262")));
```

or

```
return this.Document.Element(Find.ByText(new Regex("781|262")));
```

Choose the one that fits your needs, I don't know if the character "\" is significant for you.

You don't need the string to be a verbatim string in order to instantiate the regex class.

Comment: Thank you, but that gives a compiler error for unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you, but still, they don't work. I think the | needs to be escaped, so I can't see how the second one should work. Well, I would also think the first one would work, but same as with @, it does not.

Comment: What about new Regex(@"781|262")

Comment: Nope, still the whole page content  ._.